# Memory leaks in QPushButton or what?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, memory-leaks

Shortly: when I dragging the mouse over the QPushButton in MS Windows7 (64bit) my app eats some memory.
But if I close the widget where the buttons are then memory will be returned.

I'm using qt5 beta 2 and VC++ with crtdbg.h.

Here is my test app (Launch, open widget2 and drag mouse over the buttons on it. At the same time see task manager.)

```
//-- widget1.h
class Widget1 : public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
private:
 void callWidget2();
public:
 Widget1(QWidget* parent = 0);
 ~Widget1() {}

};

//-- widget1.cpp
Widget1::Widget1(QWidget* parent)
 :QWidget(parent)
{
 QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton(this);
 btn->setText("show widget2");
 connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget1::callWidget2);

 this->resize(100, 100);

 this->show();
}

void Widget1::callWidget2()
{
 new Widget2();
}

//-- widget2.h
class Widget2 : public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
private:

public:
 Widget2(QWidget* parent = 0);
 ~Widget2() {}

};

//-- widget2.cpp
Widget2::Widget2(QWidget* parent)
 :QWidget(parent)
{
 this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
 this->resize(300, 300);

 QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
 button->setText("btn1");

 button = new QPushButton(this);
 button->setText("btn2");
 button->move(0, 20);

 button = new QPushButton(this);
 button->setText("btn3");
 button->move(0, 40);

 button = new QPushButton(this);
 button->setText("btn4");
 button->move(0, 60);

 button = new QPushButton(this);
 button->setText("btn5");
 button->move(0, 80);

 this->show();
}

//-- main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);

 new Widget1;

 return a.exec();
}
```

This is the result of 5 minutes dragging. [image]

I can't repeat this on windows XP 32bit.

What is this?

Comment: What do you mean by "drag mouse over buttons"? Do you click? The purpose of the app is to create memory leaks??

Comment: I don't click buttons, just drag mouse pointer. Try it yourself. More moves more memory. The purpose of the app is to show that memory goes out when I just drag mouse over the buttons. I can't understand why it happens.

Comment: If you have clear example code, which behaves like that in 64 bit, but differently in 32 bit, I suggest you first go to irc to talk about it (freenode irc network, channel #qt-labs for talking about Qt *framework* development), then file a bug report (or just file the report directly, after searching it's not reported already). Saying "I have code which leaks memory on 64 bits, but not with 32 bits" at irc should probably get some attention :)

Comment: Could be style-dependent, try you see the same using another QStyle.

Comment: How do you measure leaks? Closing widget may not delete it so why do you assume that memory should be freed?

Comment: Memory should not be freed, it freed when I close widget2. So this is not a leak but why memory usage grows?
**Frank Osterfeld**, Yes, when I set app style to QWindowsStyle memory usage looks normal. So this is the problem in Windows 7  (32 and 64bit) with its style.

Comment: Sometimes Qt doesn't allocate everything at start but on first usage. Does memory grow everytime you hover button? Or does it grows once per each button. It may be not leak itself but just some lazy initialized structures for style. Did you try to check it in Qt source code?

Comment: Memory grow everytime I hover the button. Now, for example, my app using ~500MB, its not normal. This experiment works with one button on the widget.
I don't check Qt source yet.

Comment: Task opened [QTBUG-28506](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28506)